# how to clear the java script in script tag

Tags: javascript

- I want to clear the java script based on few conditions that is
  related to my project specific. I am just giving sample code snippet

  **

  Hello
         var a= 10; a = a+ 11; alert("value = "+a);
         var b= 10; b = a+ 31; alert("value = "+b);

  **

  ```
    This code will execute first script defer. If first `<script defer>`    executed, i want to clear second `<script defer>` should
  ```

  clear. it    should not execute further. How to do this

  I want to clear this script dynamically? once page loaded....how
  to write javascript to remove second script ??will it possible?

  My trial
  ** if( $('script').attr("defer") = true ){
     //clear the script in the html page } **

  what we need to add in inside if block?

Comment: It doesn't really make much sense to use "defer" on scripts that don't have a "src" attribute, and modern versions of browsers will in that case just ignore it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the first script will always execute, and therefore the second one should never run according to your requirements. Why not remove it completely from your markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the poser of LOGIC!

```
<script defer> var a= 10; a = a+ 11; alert("value = "+a);</script>
<script defer> if(a!=10) {var b= 10; b = a+ 31; alert("value = "+b);}</script>
```

Comment: Can't we remove second script dynamically? using java script tags?

Comment: You can indeed - but how to do it before it executes. If you could do that, why not just rip out the second script tag to begin with?

Comment: i tried below way --->if( $('script').attr("defer") = true ){
    //clear the script in the html page
} what i need to write in If case?